# Swift -Animation in GradientLayer not appearing in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I have different images of different foods that I add to a `UIView` (I choose to use an `UIView` instead of an `UIImageView`). The original color of the images are black and I change them to `.lightGray` using `.alwaysTemplate`.

```
// the imageWithColor function on the end turns it .lightGray: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24545102/4833705][1]
let pizzaImage = UIImage(named: "pizzaImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).imageWithColor(color1: UIColor.lightGray)
foodImages.append(pizzaImage)
```

I add the food images to the UIView in `cellForRow`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: foodCell, for: indexPath) as! FoodCell

    cell.myView.layer.contents = foodImages[indexPath.item].cgImage

    return cell
}
```

The UIView is inside a cell and in the cell's `layoutSubviews` I add a gradientLayer with an animation that gives a shimmer effect but when the cells appear on screen the animation doesn't occur.

**What's the issue?**

```
class FoodCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center
    view.tintColor = .lightGray
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .white

    setAnchors()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.5, 1]
    gradientLayer.frame = myView.frame

    let angle = 45 * CGFloat.pi / 180
    gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.duration = 2
    animation.fromValue = -self.frame.width
    animation.toValue = self.frame.width
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity

    gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "...")
}

fileprivate func setAnchors() {
    addSubview(myView)

    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not relevant, but you are saying `gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "...")` inside your `layoutSubviews` implementation. But `layoutSubviews` can be called thousands of times over the lifetime of your app. Do you really want thousands of gradients layers in every cell? This is a train wreck in the making.

Comment: That’s true, I overlooked that, thanks. I initially added the code in the init method and when it wasn’t working I thought maybe the UIView’s frame wasn’t ready yet. That’s why I added it to layoutSubviews without thinking about anything else. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Another possibly useful insight: you cannot animate a layer that is not _already_ in the layer hierarchy. This isn't just a matter of order; you cannot animate a layer _in the same code_ (i.e. the same transaction) that adds it to the layer hierarchy.

Comment: Are you saying they have to be added at separate times. For example calling func1 adds the gradient and then calling func2 adds the animation?

Comment: Here's _another_ problem. You are saying `addSubview(myView)`, meaning `self. addSubview(myView)`. But `self` is a `FoodCell: UICollectionViewCell`. It is forbidden to add a view directly to a UICollectionViewCell; you must add it to the cell's `contentView`. If your goal is to display a view behind everything else, that is what the cell's `backgroundView` is for.

Comment: why is it forbidden to add directly to the view itself as opposed to the contentView? I've always added the cell's subviews directly and never had an issue. I read your book (the whole thing) sometime ago and vaguely remember you mentioning the contentView but all the examples I've come across very few people use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192482/discussion-between-lance-samaria-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

I took @Matt's advice in the comments under the question and added myView to the cell's `contentView` property instead of the cell directly. I can't find the post but I just read that for animations to work in a cell, whichever views the animations are on needs to be added to the cell's `contentView`

I moved the gradientLayer from layoutSubviews and instead made it a lazy property.

I also moved the animation into it's own lazy property.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47937424/4833705) and set the gradientLayer's frame to the cell's `bounds` property (I initially had it set to the cell's `frame` property)

I added a function that adds the gradientLayer to myView's layer's `insertSublayer` property and call that function in `cellForRow`. Also as per @Matt's comments under my answer to prevent the gradientLayer from constantly getting added over again I add a check to see if the gradient is in the UIView's layer's hierarchy (I got the idea [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597262/4833705) even though it's used for a different reason). If it isn't there I add and if is I don't add it.

```
// I added both the animation and the gradientLayer here
func addAnimationAndGradientLayer() {

    if let _ = (myView.layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {
        print("it's already in here so don't readd it")
    } else {

        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "...") // 1. added animation
        myView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0) // 2. added the gradientLayer
        print("it's not in here so add it")
    }
}
```

To call the function to add the gradientLayer to the cell it's called in `cellForRow`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: foodCell, for: indexPath) as! FoodCell

    cell.removeGradientLayer() // remove the gradientLayer due to going to the background and back issues

    cell.myView.layer.contents = foodImages[indexPath.item].cgImage

    cell.addAnimationAndGradientLayer() // I call it here

    return cell
}
```

Updated code for the cell

```
class FoodCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center
    view.tintColor = .lightGray
    return view
}()

lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.5, 1]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

    let angle = 45 * CGFloat.pi / 180
    gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)
    return gradientLayer
}()

lazy var animation: CABasicAnimation = {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.duration = 2
    animation.fromValue = -self.frame.width
    animation.toValue = self.frame.width
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    return animation
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .white

    setAnchors()
}

func addAnimationAndGradientLayer() {

    // make sure the gradientLayer isn't already in myView's hierarchy before adding it
    if let _ = (myView.layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {
        print("it's already in here so don't readd it")
    } else {

        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "...") // 1. add animation
        myView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0) // 2. add gradientLayer
        print("it's not in here so add it")
    }
}

// this function is explained at the bottom of my answer and is necessary if you want the animation to not pause when coming from the background 
func removeGradientLayer() {

    myView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    setNeedsDisplay() // these 2 might not be necessary but i called them anyway
    layoutIfNeeded()

    if let _ = (iconImageView.layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {
        print("no man the gradientLayer is not removed")
    } else {
        print("yay the gradientLayer is removed")
    }
}

fileprivate func setAnchors() {

    self.contentView.addSubview(myView)

    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
}
```

[image]

**As a side note this BELOW works great if the users CAN’T scroll the cells (placeholder cells) but if they CAN make sure to test before adding because it's buggy**

Another problem I ran into was when I would go to the background and come back the animation wouldn't move. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43934498/4833705) (code below on how to use it) which works although in that same thread I amended that answer to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947709/4833705) to start the animation from the beginning which works **BUT** there are issues.

I noticed even though I came back from the foreground and the animation worked sometimes when I scrolled the animation got stuck. To get around it I called `cell.removeGradientLayer()` in `cellForRow` and then again as explained below. However it still got stuck when scrolling but by calling the above it got unstuck. It works for what I need it for because I only show these cells while the actual cells are loading. I'm disabling scrolling when the animation occurs anyway so I don't have to worry about it. FYI this stuck issue only seems to happen when coming back from the **background** and then **scrolling**.

I also had to remove the gradientLayer from the cell by calling `cell.removeGradientLayer()` when the app went to the background and then when it came back to the foreground I had to call `cell.addAnimationAndGradientLayer()` to add it again. I did that by adding background/foreground Notifications in the class that has the collectionView. In the accompanying Notification functions I just scroll through the visible cells and call the cell's functions that are necessary (code is also below).

```
class PersistAnimationView: UIView {

    private var persistentAnimations: [String: CAAnimation] = [:]
    private var persistentSpeed: Float = 0.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func didBecomeActive() {
        self.restoreAnimations(withKeys: Array(self.persistentAnimations.keys))
        self.persistentAnimations.removeAll()
        if self.persistentSpeed == 1.0 { //if layer was plaiyng before backgorund, resume it
            self.layer.resume()
        }
    }

    func willResignActive() {
        self.persistentSpeed = self.layer.speed

        self.layer.speed = 1.0 //in case layer was paused from outside, set speed to 1.0 to get all animations
        self.persistAnimations(withKeys: self.layer.animationKeys())
        self.layer.speed = self.persistentSpeed //restore original speed

        self.layer.pause()
    }

    func persistAnimations(withKeys: [String]?) {
        withKeys?.forEach({ (key) in
            if let animation = self.layer.animation(forKey: key) {
                self.persistentAnimations[key] = animation
            }
        })
    }

    func restoreAnimations(withKeys: [String]?) {
        withKeys?.forEach { key in
            if let persistentAnimation = self.persistentAnimations[key] {
                self.layer.add(persistentAnimation, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CALayer {
    func pause() {
        if self.isPaused() == false {
            let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
            self.speed = 0.0
            self.timeOffset = pausedTime
        }
    }

    func isPaused() -> Bool {
        return self.speed == 0.0
    }

    func resume() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.timeOffset
        self.speed = 1.0
        self.timeOffset = 0.0
        self.beginTime = 0.0
        // as per the amended answer comment these 2 lines out to start the animation from the beginning when coming back from the background
        // let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        // self.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}
```

And in the cell class instead of making **MyView** and instance of `UIView` I instead made it an instance of `PersistAnimationView` like this:

```
class FoodCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let MyView: PersistAnimationView = {
        let persistAnimationView = PersistAnimationView()
        persistAnimationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        persistAnimationView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        persistAnimationView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        persistAnimationView.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.center
        persistAnimationView.tintColor = .lightGray
        return persistAnimationView
    }()

    // everything else in the cell class is the same
```

Here are the Notifications for the class with the collectionView. The animations also stop [when the view disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627769/4833705) or [reappears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061898/4833705) so you’ll have to manage this in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear too.

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDatasource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // MARK:- View Controller Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appHasEnteredBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        addAnimationAndGradientLayerInFoodCell()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        removeGradientLayerInFoodCell()
    }

    // MARK:- Functions for Notifications
    @objc func appHasEnteredBackground() {

        removeGradientLayerInFoodCell()
    }

    @objc func appWillEnterForeground() {

        addAnimationAndGradientLayerInFoodCell()
    }

    // MARK:- Supporting Functions
    func removeGradientLayerInFoodCell() {

        // if you are using a tabBar, switch tabs, then go to the background, comeback, then switch back to this tab, without this check the animation will get stuck
        if (self.view.window != nil) {

            collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { (cell) in

                if let cell = cell as? FoodCell {
                    cell.removeGradientLayer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addAnimationAndGradientLayerInFoodCell() {

        // if you are using a tabBar, switch tabs, then go to the background, comeback, then switch back to this tab, without this check the animation will get stuck
        if (self.view.window != nil) {

            collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { (cell) in

                if let cell = cell as? FoodCell {
                    cell.addAnimationAndGradientLayer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK but your code is still wrong for the same reason as before. `cellForItemAt` will receive the same cell many times, because cells are _reused_. Thus you will add many gradient layers to the same cell.

Comment: You know you your right. That happened to me on a previous project I was working on. Frustrated the heck out me. What I did was created a function that removed the gradient and then in cellForRow before I added the image to the layer, I called that function. So 1. cell.removeGradient() 2. cell.myView.layer.contents = foodImages[indexPath.item].cgImage and 3. cell.addGradientLayer(). I'm not sure it was the most elegant way to do it but the it stopped the problem from occurring. I can also remove it in prepareForReuse but your book and plenty of posts say not to do that.

Comment: But my book also tells you the right answer. Add the gradient layer _conditionally_. Just _look_ to see if the gradient layer is already present in this cell, and if it is, don't add it again.

Comment: @matt I updated the code to check if the gradientLayer is or isn't in myView's hierarchy. It works. Thanks

Comment: @matt not sure if you have time to look this over but I had to do a considerable amount of work to keep these animations working. Going to the background and back they stop, switching tabs they stop, switching tabs, going to the background, then coming back and then coming back to this tab they stop. Animations are a lot of work man. I had to constantly add and remove them again.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try this, put this code inside it's own function:

```
func setUpGradient() {
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]    
    ...
    gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "...")
}
```

Then in your init function call it

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpGradient()
}
```

It seems like your problem might be the layoutSubviews can be called a lot, but the init function will only be called when the view is initialized with a frame. Also putting the setup code in its own function will make it easier to do other things like update the gradient layer's frame if the frame changes.

Comment: hey thanks, I actually tried that earlier but I did it it a little differently. I created the function then call it from cellForRow. It didn't work. Thanks for the help though

Comment: I just tried it your way but nothing. Thanks though

Comment: No problem :) Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: I just got it working, check it out when you can. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome that’s an amazing solution!